# Typedef and function declaration not working together

Tags: c++, typedef

I was tweaking a bit of GDAL code, and am using a typedef like this

```
typedef CPLErr (*MYWriter)( double dfLevel, int nPoints, double *padfX, double *padfY, void * );
```

which is being used in a class like this

```
class GDALGenerator
{
...blah...
public:
    MYWriter pfnWriter;
    GDALGenerator( int nWidth, int nHeight, MYWriter pfnWriter, void *pWriterCBData );
...blah...
};
```

but in the same file, below the GDALGenerator class when I create the function like so

```
CPLErr MYWriter( double dfLevel, int nPoints, double *padfX, double *padfY, void *pInfo )
{}
```

I get this error

> Error 2   error C2365: 'MYWriter' : redefinition; previous definition
>   was 'typedef' f:\projects\map\somecpp\somecpp.cpp 1330    MyProjectName

I'm confused, because a standard GDAL function is being used exactly like this, and it works fine (the class is in a separate DLL in that case). I just made a copy of the function with the different name, and it doesn't work.

Comment: Both the `typedef` and the function have the same name. You have to rename one or the other. I also recommend you look at [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) which can be used for all kind of functions, not only stand-alone or static member functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you cannot use the type name as a function name, only as a type of a variable.

I hope this makes it clear:

```
CPLErr f( double dfLevel, int nPoints, double *padfX, double *padfY, void *pInfo )
{}
MYWriter foo = f;
```

``

Comment: Thanks. I guess I'd have to change the name in the class too.

Comment: @nav, nope, your member variable has the type of a function pointer (your typedef), and the name "pfnWriter", this is completely fine. You can write `GDALGenerator g(...); g.pfnWriter = f;` after the lines in my answer.